# Create a function that randomly picks an image but does not repeat

Tags: javascript, arrays

So this is the code I have so far, it works perfectly to choose random images when you click the button on the screen, but it will repeat some pictures. In the final function there will be around 50 images. Any ideas what I need to add to this to stop it repeating images? Thank you! :)

```js
const imageArray = [
  "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1476547362848-ed2a9f99cd29?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=5b4647c9e25267c25866936c916e4aa8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1350&q=80",
  "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1506017669510-0bcbe8003d70?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=9403f5d4ac23a5726bfc3c8308b31c01&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1350&q=80",
  "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1489447068241-b3490214e879?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=a85cb0d68de38ae2aa00d8a9663a320a&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1350&q=80"
];

const image = document.querySelector("img");
const button = document.querySelector("button");

window.onload = () => generateRandomPicture(imageArray);

button.addEventListener("click", () => generateRandomPicture(imageArray));

function generateRandomPicture(array) {
  let randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length);
  image.setAttribute("src", array[randomNum]);
}
```

```html
<button type="button">Click</button>
<img src="" />
```

Comment: Just shuffle the array once and iterate through it.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Please first ***>>>[Search for related topics on SO](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+random+image+click+repeat+site%3Astackoverflow.com)<<<*** and  if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [`[<>]`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.